Solution to failure of Window Chrome and Firefox Print to reproduce audio element controls
On Windows Chrome and Firefox browsers, this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
BEFORE
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
AFTER
</body>
</html>

produces on screen a control panel as expected e.g.

But when printed it produces:

How can I get the print version to include the control panel, accurately representing the screen version?

Perhaps print backgrounds?

That works! How... perverted. Thanks. Please add as an answer so I can accept it.

You can select to print backgrounds in the print dialog, alternatively have CSS specifically for printing.
This works for me in Chrome
<style media="print">
    audio, video {
  background-color: #ccc;
  /* Replace with your desired background color */
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  /* For Webkit-based browsers (e.g., Chrome, Safari) */
  print-color-adjust: exact;
  /* For other browsers */
}
</style>

Here in a web page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Print Test</title>
  <!-- uncomment the link tags below if you use external stylesheets, the code belongs in the media="print" stylesheet" -->
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" -->
  <style media="print">
    audio,
video {
  background-color: #ccc;
  /* Replace with your desired background color */
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  /* For Webkit-based browsers (e.g., Chrome, Safari) */
  print-color-adjust: exact;
  /* For other browsers */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <audio controls>
        <source src="audio-file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
  <video controls>
        <source src="video-file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video element.
    </video>
</body>
</html>


Thanks. Chrome "Background graphics" / Firefox "Print backgrounds" works 100% here.

As an option for the page author not user, the CSS works here, requiring the background-color to be set to match the background /around/ the control panel. However it works equally with background-color removed, whereupon media="print" becomes redundant. Would you please verify? Thanks.

If you have the CSS without the media, then it will work on the print too. If you do NOT have the CSS it will only work on screen - so you can just have the CSS if you do not need to do other stuff when printing. For example have some frame from the video as cover image instead of the video

I take it you're saying I can omit media-"print" and background-color... if I'm not doing any other stuff when printing only. Thanks.
